# If I upgrade my websphere MQ manager in my application, will there be any impact?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I want to know if there are any coding impacts if I upgrade my queue managers from WMQ v7.5 to WMQ V8.0.0.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you look at the Knowledge center page "[What's changed in IBM MQ Version 8.0.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q001060_.htm)"

I am going to assume you are concerned with IBM MQ Classes for Java and IBM MQ Classes for JMS based on the additional [[java](/questions/tagged/java)] tag you added.  If the client applications will be using the MQ v8.0 jar files, the biggest change is that Java 7 is now required.  Below are some links that may be of interest from the Knowledge center page above:

> **[Deprecation: SSLv3 protocol](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q123420_.htm?view=kc)**
>   From IBM MQ Version 8.0.0, Fix Pack 2, the SSLv3 protocol and the use
>   of some IBM MQ CipherSpecs is deprecated.
>
> **[Deprecation: weaker cryptographic algorithms](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q123425_.htm?view=kc)**
>   From IBM MQ Version 8.0.0, Fix Pack 3, the support for weaker
>   cryptographic algorithms is deprecated.
>
> **[Java and JMS: changes to character string conversion](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q127520_.htm?view=kc)**
>   From IBM MQ Version 8.0, some of the default behavior regarding
>   character string conversion with Java and JMS clients has changed.
>
> **[Java and JMS: changes to CipherSuite support](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q120525_.htm?view=kc)**
>   The support for SSL/TLS CipherSuites in the IBM MQ classes for Java
>   and IBM MQ classes for JMS has changed.
>
> **[Java: changes for Java 7](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q123560_.htm?view=kc)**
>   In order to support Java 7, changes have been made to IBM MQ classes
>   for Java and IBM MQ classes for JMS.
>
> **[Java: Changes to IBM MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q115900_.htm?view=kc)**
>   For IBM MQ Version 8.0, an unwanted dependency on connector.jar has
>   been removed and changes have been made to APIs for public classes.
>
> **[Java: changes to MQException and MQDataException class logging](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q119220_.htm?view=kc)**
>   The logging functionality of the com.ibm.mq.MQException class, which
>   wrote details of new MQExceptions to a log, has been removed for IBM
>   MQ Version 8.0.
>
> **[JMS: changes to Bytes and Stream message states](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q123570_.htm?view=kc)**
>   In order to support Java Message Service 2.0, changes have been made
>   to IBM MQ Version 8.0.0, Fix Pack 2.
>
> **[JMS: Exception listener changes in Version 8.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q129610_.htm?view=kc)**
>   In IBM MQ Version 8.0, when using IBM MQ classes for JMS, changes are
>   made to the way in which an application's JMS ExceptionListener is
>   invoked.
>
> **[JMS: changes to IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q115970_.htm?view=kc)**
>   For IBM MQ Version 8.0, a number of changes are made to IBM MQ classes
>   for JMS.
>
> **[JMS: changes to JAR files for JMS 2.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q115920_.htm?view=kc)**
>   In order to support Java Message Service 2.0, changes have been made
>   to IBM MQ Version 8.0.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation, got my answer.. :)